# Laravel in Shared Hosting

Tags: shared-hosting, laravel-5.6

I am trying to install a Laravel application in Shared Hosting following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g8G3YQtQt4) tutorial where my server's PHP version is 7.1.17 and my Laravel version is 5.6.15.

When I am trying to browse my application using Chrome I can see only a White page, even no error is there.

I tried to debug the application and found that below code of `index.php` is not working.

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

What is the solution of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no error_log or your error log are empty

1. Check if it's a php version is a latest 7.1 or higher
2. Make sure YOUR_PATH_DIR are correct

$app = require_once **DIR**.'/YOUR_PATH_DIR/bootstrap/app.php';
require **DIR**.'/YOUR_PATH_DIR/vendor/autoload.php';